# How to find if specific changeset within the parents in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am a git background and just moved to a project where is uses mercurial, the projects is branched with heads model.

Before pushing things to our testing server, I want to make sure that production head is one of my parents list. is there is a command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually I found a way to do so using "revsets" of mercurial.

in order to list all ancestors for specific changeset, we can use the command

```
hg log -r "ancestors(84e5bc6fd673)"
```

now in order to find specific changeset in these parents, we can use the matching function like below

```
hg log -r "ancestors(84e5bc6fd673) and id(hh6cjb9c48se)"
```

so if hh6cjb9c48se is part of 84e5bc6fd673 parents it will be printed to the terminal.

Comment: `matching()` is wrong choice. Use `id()` for cset-hash (or use hash directly)

Comment: Some beautifications 1) revset can be defined as parametrized  `[revsetalias]` (less retyping) 2) you can format output with template for more smart presentation, something like (as is, without parameters and aliasing) (TBT!) `-T "{ifeq(node, hh6cjb9c48se, 'Found', 'Not found')}\n"`